# Is it possible to have parameters for anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

Given

```
var stuffs = [
    { id : 1, name : "orange"},
    { id : 2, name : "apple"}, 
    { id : 0, name:"grapes"}
];
var filterMethod1 = new function(o){return (o.id>=1);}; // this gives undefined error for o
function filterMethod2(o) {return (o.id>=1);};
```

Why is using anonymous function not working for array filter() method?

```
var temp = stuffs.filter(new function(o){ return (o.id>=1);}); // o is undefined if used this way
```

Using declared function works fine:

```
var temp = stuffs.filter(filterMethod2);
```

Comment: `new function(o) {...}` is trying to use the function as a constructor.

Comment: Where did you get that `new` from?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `new` to create an anonymous function. The `new` keyword in Javascript is used to call a function as an object constructor, and the parameters are typically used by the constructor to initialize properties of the object. Just put the anonymous function in the argument to `filter()`.:

```
var temp = stuffs.filter(function(o){ return (o.id>=1);});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of the "new" keyword and it should work.

Comment: A more complete answer would be to explain **why** removing the `new` keyword would solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @Pointy Huh? `.filter()` is passing values to the function.